# I need to write a program that reads integers from stdin and, for each integer read, prints pi to that number of decimal places

Tags: python

Doing some lab questions and I came across this one, been stuck on it for ages not sure what to do from here, heres my code:

```
    import sys
    import math

    for number in sys.stdin:
        number = number.strip()
        pi = str(math.pi)
        print(format(pi, number))
```

My code is just printing pi, also i forgot to mention Im still a beginner so we haven't come across every technique.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this task?

Comment: The second argument to `format` has to be an appropriate format specifier, not just a number of decimal places.

Comment: I need to print pi to an unknown amount of decimal places, eg 2 - 3.14, but my code prints pi to 15 decimal for some reason.

Comment: You can also make use of indexing since you want to cast pi to str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use round instead format:

```
import sys
import math

for n in sys.stdin:
     number = int(n.strip())
     pi = math.pi
     print(round(pi, number))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use indexing.

```
import sys
import math
for n in sys.stdin:
    number = int(n.strip())
    pi = str(math.pi)
    print(pi[:number+2])
```

Comment: But they don't want to multiply pi with a number.

Comment: Unclear question, did not understand what OP actually wanted. Apologies.